# Override KendoUI Autocomplete selected value

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How do I override the function that takes the value selected or typed in by the user and puts it into the triggering input?

E.g. my datasource is:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Tim"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Bob"
    }
]
```

I want the autocomplete to return:

```
<span class="my-class">Tim</span>
```

Instead of just `Tim`

I am using this as an editor for a cell in my KendoUI Grid so I once the cell is no longer being edited its HTML is like so:

```
<td role="gridcell"><span class="my-class">Tim</span></td>
```

---

Here is the editor for the grid column:

```
function partNumberScanner(container, options)
{
  partId = options.model.id;
  var autoC = $('<input class="k-input data-value-field="id" k-textbox part-sniffer" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
  autoC.appendTo(container);
  autoC.kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "idealForm",
    dataValueField: "id",
    delay: 50,
    dataSource: {
      serverFiltering: true,
      transport: {
        read: {
          url: ROOT+"part/fetch-parts",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json"
        }
      },
      error: function(e) {
        alert(e.errorThrown+"\n"+e.status+"\n"+e.xhr.responseText) ;
      },
      schema: {
        id: "id",
        idealForm: "idealForm",
        manufacturer: "manufacturer"
      }
    },
    minLength: 5,
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "Start typing...",
    //template: '#= "<li class=\'k-item\' role=\'option\' data-manufacturer=\'"+manufacturer+"\'>"+idealForm+"</li>" #',
    select: function(e)
    {
      matchedPartData = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
      manufacturer = matchedPartData.manufacturer;
    },
    change: function(e) {
     // selectedPart = this.value();
      $.each(partData, function(i, v){
        if(partId == v.id)
        {
          targetId = i ;
          return false
        }
      })
      partData[targetId].manufacturer = manufacturer;
      grid.dataSource.sync();


    }
  });
}
```

The problem is the `change` callback is called while the cell is still in edit mode, so I need to alter the value that is returned from `change`.

---

I am making something where a user types in a part number, and if parts are found starting with what the user has typed, they are shown in the autocomplete and can be selected.

Once the value has been typed and the grid cell leaves edit mode, bootstrap popover needs to be placed on the value that is now in the cell.

Hope I have explained it well enough.

---

I tried something like that earlier but still couldn't get it to work. I have:

```
template: "<span data-content=''>#= partNumber #</span>"
```

What I need to happen is once a selection is made, an AJAX call is made which brings back data that gets put into the data-content attr of cell.

---

```
change: function(e) {
...
options.model.set(options.field, '<span class="part-intel">'+this.value()+'</span>');
grid.dataSource.sync();
$.ajax({
          url: ROOT+'part/partAnalysis',
          async: false,
          success: function(data)
          {
            element = container.find('span.part-intel');
            /*element.popover({
            html: true,
            content: data
          })*/
            alert(element.html()) // Shows undefined
           // element.popover('show');
          }
        })
})
```

Comment: You missed an open curly brackets before `Bob` element, don't you?

Comment: @OnaBai Sorry, have fixed that. It's just an example.

Comment: Yeah!, I know, by the way, you are doing pretty _strange_ things...

Comment: @OnaBai Oh, you don't know the half of it ;) lol

Comment: @OnaBai I have updated my question to explain what I am trying to achieve a little better.

Answer (score 0):

For setting the value you should use `value` function. Doing it from inside the `change` event handler is:

```
change: function(e) {
    e.sender.value("New Value");
}
```

**Edit** Since in your case you have access to the row model since in the editor function `partNumberScanner` you receive it in `options` you can simply do:

```
change: function(e) {
    options.model.set(options.field, "New Value");
}
```

Comment: It is still putting the selected value into the cell and not

e.sender.value("New Value");

If I alert it I get New Value, it's just not returning it :(

Comment: That gets me the value into the field but how do I attach a call back to it after the k-input input blurs? Please see my edit on what I amd trying to achieve. Also, when I go back to edit the cell, the contents show '<span class="part-intel">New Value</span>' when it needs to only show 'New Value'.